# How to make instance of Applicative a certain data type

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative

I'm reading Graham Hutton book on Haskell, and don't no how to proceed in one part of an excercise. The excercise says as follows:

Given the following type expressions

```
data Expr a = Var a | Val Int | Add (Expr a) (Expr a) deriving Show
```

that contain variables of some type a, show how to make this type into instances of Functor, Applicative and Monad classes. With the aid of an example, explain what the `>>=` operator for this type does.

---

I have had problems defining the `<*>` operator of Applicative. The type of `<*>` is:

```
(<*>) :: Expr (a -> b) -> Expr a -> Expr b
```

I don't understand how `(Val n) <*> mx` might work, because theoretically I need to provide a `Expr b`, but all I have is a `Expr a` and no function to convert (`a -> b`).

I also don't understand what to do in the `(Add l r) <*> mx` case.

---

This is my implementation.

```
instance Functor Expr where
    --fmap :: (a -> b) -> Expr a -> Expr b
    fmap g (Var x) = Var (g x)
    fmap g (Val n) = Val n
    fmap g (Add l r) = Add (fmap g l) (fmap g r)


instance Applicative Expr where
    --pure :: a -> Expr a
    pure = Var

    -- <*> :: Expr (a -> b) -> Expr a -> Expr b
    (Var g) <*> mx = fmap g mx
    --(Val n) <*> mx = ???
    --(Add l r) <*> mx = ???

instance Monad Expr where
    -- (>>=) :: Expr a -> (a -> Expr b) -> Expr b
    (Var x) >>= g = g x
    (Val n) >>= g = Val n
    (Add l r) >>= g = Add (l >>= g) (r >>= g)


expr = Add (Add (Var 'a') (Val 4)) (Var 'b')
```

Finally, I have a doubt with respect to the >>= in the monad. The idea of this operator is to do things like substituting variables? Like:

```
expr >>= (\x -> if x == 'a' then Val 6 else Var x) >>= (\x -> if x == 'b' then Val 7 else Var x)
```

Comment: In `(Val n) <*> mx`, what's the type of `n`? (note the type of `<*>`)

Comment: data Expr a = Var a | Val Int | ...   It's an Int

Comment: Ah sorry I misread I thought it was `Var`...

Comment: I also had trouble with this exercise. The solutions I found on the Internet don't seem to be correct because they tend to define both `Val k <*> _ = Val k` and `_ <*> Val k = Val k` which give different results for an expression like `Val 0 <*> Val 1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you correctly note, in the case:

```
(Val n) <*> mx = ???
```

you have:

```
Val n :: Expr (a -> b)
mx :: Expr a
```

and you need to produce an `Expr b`.  Do you recall the case:

```
fmap g (Val n) = ???
```

when you had:

```
g :: a -> b
Val n :: Expr a
```

and you needed to produce an `Expr b`?  You found a solution there.

For the case:

```
(Add l r) <*> mx
```

you have:

```
l :: Expr (a -> b)
r :: Expr (a -> b)
mx :: Expr a
```

and you need to produce an `Expr b`.  If only you had some function that could take `l` and `mx` and create an `Expr b`.  Such a function, if it existed, would probably have signature:

```
someFunc :: Expr (a -> b) -> Expr a -> Expr b
```

Of course, with `someFunc l mx` and `someFunc r mx`, both of type `Expr b`, it would be a shame to only use one.  If there was some way of **constructing** an `Expr b` from two `Expr b` parts, that would really be the bees' knees.

Answer (score 3):

When you have defined `pure` and `(>>=)`, one possible definition of `(<*>)` is

```
(<*>) = Control.Monad.ap
```

where `ap` is defined in the standard library as

```
ap :: Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
ap mf mx = do
  f <- mf
  x <- mx
  pure (f x)
```

In fact any definition of `(<*>)` must be equivalent to that if there is a `Monad` instance.

Answer (score 3):

You've slightly mis-stated what types you have available in the `Val n` case. You don't have an `Expr a`, but rather an `Expr (a -> b)`, and no `a` or `b` at all (nor even a function from `a -> b`, because `Val` contains only an `Int`). In fact, this case is easy precisely *because* you have no useful values around: the only reasonable thing you could possibly do is produce an output using the constructor `Val`, because you have no way to fabricate a `b` from thin air. The type of `Val` can specialize to `Val :: Int -> Expr b`, and happily, you have an `Int` lying around, so you can write:

```
(Val n) <*> mx = Val n
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented it as follows:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}

instance Functor Expr where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> Expr a -> Expr b
  fmap _ (Val k) = Val k
  fmap g (Var x) = Var (g x)
  fmap g (Add expr1 expr2) = Add (fmap g expr1) (fmap g expr2)

instance Applicative Expr where
  pure :: a -> Expr a
  pure = Var
  (<*>) :: Expr (a -> b) -> Expr a -> Expr b
  _ <*> Val k = Val k
  eg <*> Var x = fmap (\g -> g x) eg
  eg <*> Add e1 e2 = Add (eg <*> e1) (eg <*> e2)

instance Monad Expr where
  (>>=) :: Expr a -> (a -> Expr b) -> Expr b
  Val k >>= _ = Val k
  Var x >>= g = g x
  Add e1 e2 >>= g = Add (e1 >>= g) (e2 >>= g)
```

However, I'm not sure how to answer the last part of the question. I suspect there's something missing in the Monad equations. For example, if I define the following function

```hs
simplify :: Num a => Expr a -> Expr a
simplify (Val k) = Val k
simplify (Var x) = Var x
simplify (Add expr1 expr2) = do
  x <- simplify expr1
  y <- simplify expr2
  return (x + y)
```

And try to do the following, for example,

```hs
simplify (Add (Add (Var 5) (Val 12)) (Add (Val 10) (Var 8)))
```

I only get `Val 12`, which doesn't seem to make sense.

---

*Added 2023-06-04:*

I wrote Prof. Hutton and he sent me the official solution of this exercise:

> ```
> instance Functor Expr where
>   -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> Expr a -> Expr b
>   fmap g (Var x) = Var (g x)
>   fmap g (Val n) = Val n
>   fmap g (Add l r) = Add (fmap g l) (fmap g r)
>
> instance Applicative Expr where
>   -- pure :: a -> Expr a
>   pure = Var
>   --  :: Expr (a -> b) -> Expr a -> Expr b
>   Var g  e = fmap g e
>   Val n  e = Val n
>   (Add l r)  e = Add (l  e) (r  e)
>
> instance Monad Expr where
>   -- (>>=) :: Expr a -> (a -> Expr b) -> Expr b
>   (Var x) >>= g = g x
>   (Val n) >>= g = Val n
>   (Add l r) >>= g = Add (l >>= g) (r >>= g)
> ```
>
> The >>= operator implements the concept of variable substitution, in
> which variables are replaced by other expressions. For example:
>
> ```
> let e = Add (Val 1) (Var ’x’)  
> :type e  
> e :: Expr Char  
> let g ’x’ = Val 2  
> :type g  
> g :: Char -> Expr a  
> e >>= g  
> Add (Val 1) (Val 2)
> ```

Comment: This confused me too. Graham Hutton says the monad is doing substitution. 
https://youtu.be/ZgUEbbZYpYc?t=880

Comment: Yes, I actually wrote him an email and he sent me the official solution. I'll post it as an answer.